# Cannot understand NHibernate lazy loading

Tags: nhibernate, lazy-loading

Thanks for clearing my doubt **Radim Köhler**. Really you saved me. I have been trying to understand this for few days. So I was thinking in the wrong direction, its the debug mode I should understand.
this is the reply you send to me **Just before starting to observe any object in the Debug window, call: session.Clear(). From that moment, only stuff already loaded will be available later.
So, in debug window, we should now see some exception about lazy loading failure...**

As you said I have added session.Clear() in my code, but I could not find the exception.
where to keep session.Clear()? if possible please edit my code. My code is like

```
public class EntityUserDetails:IUserDetails
{
    private ISession _session;
    public EntityUserDetails(ISession session)
    {
        _session = session;
    }

    public bool GetUserDetails(string userId,string password)
    {
        var user = (from userDetails in _session.Query<UserDetails>()
                    where userDetails.UserId == userId && userDetails.Password == password
                    select userDetails);

        //_session.Clear();

        foreach (var get in user)
        {

        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just try to access `user.Products` and because **user** *(instance of UserDetails)* is loaded lazily *([based on your mapping](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26998748/1679310))* - the exception should be thrown

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare the properties virtual?